# libgdx SpriteBatch render to texture

Tags: android, opengl-es, libgdx

Is it possible to render to texture using SpriteBatch in libGdx (Java engine for Android/Desktop)? If so, how do it?

Basically I want to render everything to 320 x 240 region of 512 x 256 texture and than scale region to fit screen (in landscape mode). This way I want to eliminate artifacts which happen when I scale alpha blended textures independently. If there is any other way to remove such artifacts, please point them out :)

And is there any online documentation for libGdx?

Comment: I am interested in such a feature. After casting a glance at the 'SpriteBatch' code, though, I don't reckon that it would be trivial to implement such a feature -and that it would involve recompiling the library. I added some functions to 'Pixmap' (on the native side) in the past, but this seems more encumbering.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

This snippet was given to me on the LibGDX forum and it works flawlessly.

```
private float m_fboScaler = 1.5f;
private boolean m_fboEnabled = true;
private FrameBuffer m_fbo = null;
private TextureRegion m_fboRegion = null;

public void render(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
{
    int width = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
    int height = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();

    if(m_fboEnabled)      // enable or disable the supersampling
    {                  
        if(m_fbo == null)
        {
            // m_fboScaler increase or decrease the antialiasing quality

            m_fbo = new FrameBuffer(Format.RGB565, (int)(width * m_fboScaler), (int)(height * m_fboScaler), false);
            m_fboRegion = new TextureRegion(m_fbo.getColorBufferTexture());
            m_fboRegion.flip(false, true);
        }

        m_fbo.begin();
    }

    // this is the main render function
    my_render_impl();

    if(m_fbo != null)
    {
        m_fbo.end();

        spriteBatch.begin();         
        spriteBatch.draw(m_fboRegion, 0, 0, width, height);               
        spriteBatch.end();
    }   
}
```

Comment: The point of using a TextureRegion wrapped around the frame buffer for the sake of keeping the texture flipped is well appreciated here. Newcomers take note.

Comment: I'm having some issues implementing this:
http://i.gyazo.com/7329707597bf94974dfd76fc1f33285d.gif  

If I draw my spriteBatch, everything looks fine, but when I try to capture things in a FBO, I have issues with the FBO drawing all the stuff that was previously rendered as well. Any ideas?

Comment: Ah, if anyone else is running into this issue, a glClear call should go right after fbo.begin().

Answer (score 3):

For the moment, I would recommend you to use `Pixmap`s. You see, there are not many functions written for them, but apparently you can write a `Pixmap` (with alpha channel) to another one (`pm1.drawPixmap(pm2, srcx, srcy, w, h, ...)`), providing that you don't want to scale it (you may scale the composition later, but the proportion the pictures used in the composition won't be resized... unless you write a resizing function).

If you want to do more complex stuff (like writing a string using a `BitmapFont` into a `Texture` for later manipulation, or writing it into a `Pixmap` and then uploading it to the video memory), then... then tell me if you succeed (as I want to go into that direction to optimize). I think that the best would be to add the needed functions to *libgdx*...

Anyway, don't take anything I wrote here as an undeniable truth- if I get further, I will update.

The **documentation** I found is somewhat limited -I'm sure you've gone through it already. There's information in the badlogic's blog and in the googlecode project page -and also there's a relatively good book written by Mario, "Beginning Android Games". Also, there are a few (very basic) videos. And don't forget that you can consult source and the beautiful examples...

Also, you can always ask in the forum: http://badlogicgames.com/forum/

**UPDATE**: Your answer using the `FrameBuffer` and `TextureRegion` is undeniably much better. I leave this one just because it mentions the documentation.