# Merging two Texture Regions

Tags: libgdx, textures

In my LibGDX game I have a TextureRegion1, which I would like it to serve as a base TextureRegion. Then I have TextureRegion2, which should be placed on top of the first one.

There is the 'obvious solution' and that is to render those two TextureRegions on top of each other. But that would require more rendering time and when rendering the whole map with 10 layers on each time, the graphics processor wouldn't handle it.

So is there a way to merge two TextureRegions in LibGDX?

Comment: Yes, i think is possible with the Pixmap class.

Comment: But how to achieve that?

Comment: Render your texture region to a pixmap, instead of a spritebatch, and create the texture with the constructor that takes a pixmap :) Look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7551669/libgdx-spritebatch-render-to-texture this can help

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks. If you would posted it as an anwser, I would accept it.