# how to write a text in a Texture Object in libGDX

Tags: java, android, libgdx, textures

I´m trying to write some text in different Texture objects in libGDX. Is it possible to merge fonts with Texture objects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do this.
You can use the same approach as used here to [write to a TextureRegion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7632680/2598349) with `SpriteBatch`.